# generate bootstrap grid dynamically on jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, bootstrap-4

I have a hashmap that contains item name and its children . For example:

key: Item 1 value: item1_child1, item1_child2, item1_child3

Key: Item 2 value: item2_child1, item2_child2, item2_child3

Key: Item 3 value: item3_child1 item3_child2

From this map, i need to generate a bootstrap grid like this:
[image: Grid]

If number of children on each item are only 2, then item 3 should also come on row 1

Similarly if there are 4 items that contains 3 chilren, then item 4 should come below item 2

How to generate the rows and columns dynamically based on bootstrap.

I tried with :

```
<div class="container">
        <c:forEach var="entry" items="${item}" varStatus="loop">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-xs-6}"
                    style="text-align: center;">
                    <div>${entry.key}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <c:forEach var="child" items="${entry.value}">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <div >
                            <img src="#">${child.getName()}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
```

It generates each item on different rows. Could you please suggest me how can i achieve grid shown in image.

Comment: Create a list of rows, each row containing a list of items, using Java code, in the controller. The JSP will then just have to iterate through the rows, and to iterate througn the items in each row. Doing that in Java is pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I made a list on controller and yeah was easy to iterate on jsp :)